# How can I remove prior group and create a new one in Google Sheets apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create an apps script that creates collapsable groups of "tasks" under a "milestone". When run, the program should update the group of task rows beneath a set milestone row (remove the old one and setup the new one). I've been able to create the groups correctly, but not remove old ones.

When I update the sheet and run the program, it creates stacked groups instead of removing the old ones. I haven't been able to find a solution to this in any of the documentation. Any advice?

[Here is a link to the sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Iy7tDN3-W5H2335qo7CCZQn1csm-JhzGQ1amU37jlHk/edit#gid=1128072581)
[Spreadsheet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ45D.png)

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
function updateTaskMilestoneTest() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ganttSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Gantt Chart");
  const roleSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Roles");
  var lastCol = ganttSheet.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = ganttSheet.getLastRow();
  var headerRow = ganttSheet.getRange('headerRow').getRow();
  var firstTask = headerRow + 1;
  var taskNumCol = ganttSheet.getRange('taskNum').getColumn();
  var taskCol = ganttSheet.getRange('taskNames').getColumn();
  var roleCol = roleSheet.getRange('Roles').getColumn();
  var taskRoleCol = ganttSheet.getRange('taskRole').getColumn();
  var taskScanMarkerCell = ganttSheet.getRange(lastRow +1, taskCol);
  var lastTaskRow = taskScanMarkerCell.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  var lastRoleRow = roleSheet.getRange('Roles').getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
  var rolesRange = roleSheet.getRange(1, roleCol, lastRoleRow, 1);
  var taskStartWeekCol = ganttSheet.getRange('startWeek').getColumn();
  var taskStatusCol = ganttSheet.getRange('taskStatus').getColumn();
  var taskExpDurationCol = ganttSheet.getRange('expDuration').getColumn();
  var ganttWeeksRow = ganttSheet.getRange('ganttWeeks').getRow();
  var ganttFirstWeekCol = ganttSheet.getRange('firstWeek').getColumn();
  var defaultBGColor = "#ffffff";
  var roleColors = rolesRange.getBackgrounds();
  //identify selected row
  var selection = ss.getSelection();
  var selectionRange = selection.getActiveRange();
  var selectedTaskRow = selectionRange.getRow();
  
  //reset background of the task row
  var taskRowRange = ganttSheet.getRange(selectedTaskRow, 1, 1, lastCol);
  taskRowRange.setBackground(defaultBGColor);

  Logger.log(selectedTaskRow);

  //run the program for the single row
  const updateTask = {
    "taskNumber" : ganttSheet.getRange(selectedTaskRow, taskNumCol).getValue(),
    "milestoneStatus" : Number.isInteger(ganttSheet.getRange(selectedTaskRow, taskNumCol).getValue()), //true or false
    "name" : ganttSheet.getRange(selectedTaskRow, taskCol).getValue(),
    "status" : ganttSheet.getRange(selectedTaskRow, taskStatusCol).getValue(),
    "taskRole" : ganttSheet.getRange(selectedTaskRow, taskRoleCol).getValue(),
    "assignee" : [],
    "dependency" : {
      "status" : [],
      "parent" : [],
      "type" : [],
      "buffer" : []
    },
    "startDate" : [],
    "endDate" : [],
    "duration" : []
  }

  Logger.log(updateTask.milestoneStatus); 

  var checkTaskCell = ganttSheet.getRange(selectedTaskRow, taskCol);
  var checkTaskCellValue = checkTaskCell.getValue();
  var checkTaskRoleCell = ganttSheet.getRange(selectedTaskRow, taskRoleCol);
  var checkTaskRoleCellValue = checkTaskRoleCell.getValue();
  var checkTaskStartWeekCell = ganttSheet.getRange(selectedTaskRow, taskStartWeekCol);
  var checkTaskStartWeekValue = checkTaskStartWeekCell.getValue();
  var checkTaskExpDurationCell = ganttSheet.getRange(selectedTaskRow, taskExpDurationCol);
  var checkTaskExpDurationValue = checkTaskExpDurationCell.getValue();
  var ganttTaskRange = ganttSheet.getRange(selectedTaskRow, ganttFirstWeekCol, 1, lastRow);
}
```

The code identifies a milestone based on its number (that works fine), and then creates a group with all the rows between the milestone row and the next milestone row. This all works fine.

But when I update the sheet, such as creating a new milestone, or simply run the program again, it creates a new group that is stacked with the old. I want any prior groups to be removed before creating the new one.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `When run, the program should update the group of task rows beneath a set milestone row (remove the old one and setup the new one). I've been able to create the groups correctly, but not remove old ones.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike I [made a video talking through how the program should function](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yxaiHiI9_cAuGye_o1R_sb0xNyAOxW97/view?usp=sharing). Hopefully that clarifies what it should do (and what it's not doing).

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested your script using your provided Spreadsheet and I run `updateTaskMilestoneTest()` as a test, unfortunately, I cannot replicate the situation in your video. Can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current situation?

Comment: @Tanaike Currently, the create group part of the "updateTaskMilestoneTest()" function only runs if the active/selected row is a milestone, which is indicated by the # in column A being a whole number (e.g., "1.00"). If the selected row is a milestone, then it will create a group below it. It does this every time the code runs, which creates redundant groups. I want a new group to replace any old groups.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation. But, I would like to support you. So, when I could correctly replicate your situation. I would like to think of a solution.